Duplicating Last Item of First Page and not getiing last item in RecycleView
i am making app from Laravel Api, i am stuck into problem that i am fetching the list of posts but when i scroll down to get second page i am not getting last post instead getting last post of first page...
see here 6th part is repeating
this is my adapter

public class PartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Post.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final int TYPE_POST = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_PART = 1;

    private Context context;
    private Post post;

    public PartAdapter(Context context, Post post) {
        this.context = context;
        this.post = post;
        this.parts = post != null && post.getParts() != null ? post.getParts() : new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setPost(Post post) {
        this.post = post;
        this.parts = post != null && post.getParts() != null ? new ArrayList<>(post.getParts()) : new ArrayList<>();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addParts(List<Post.Part> newParts) {
        if (newParts != null && !newParts.isEmpty()) {
            int startPosition = parts.size();
            for (Post.Part newPart : newParts) {
                if (!parts.contains(newPart)) {
                    parts.add(newPart);
                }
            }
            // Log to check added parts and total parts
            Log.d("PartAdapter", "Parts before: " + startPosition + ", Parts added: " + newParts.size() + ", Total parts: " + parts.size());
            notifyItemRangeInserted(startPosition, newParts.size());
        }
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return TYPE_POST;
        } else {
            return TYPE_PART;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_POST) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_post_part, parent, false);
            return new PostViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_part, parent, false);
            return new PartViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == TYPE_POST) {
            ((PostViewHolder) holder).bind(post);
        } else {
            ((PartViewHolder) holder).bind(parts.get(position - 1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (post == null || parts == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return parts.size() + 1;
    }

    class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        
    }

    class PartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        
    }
}


this is how i fetch posts in Activity .. i have tried lot thing but nothing seems to work,, stuck here for last 24 hours ,, please help
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                if (!isLoading && linearLayoutManager != null && linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == partAdapter.getItemCount() - 1) {
                    fetchPost(50);
                }
            }
        });

        fetchPost(50);

private void fetchPost(int postId) {
        if (isLoading) return;
        isLoading = true;

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null);
        ApiService apiService = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);
        Call<Post> call = apiService.getPostsByParts("Bearer " + token, postId, currentPage);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Post post = response.body();
                    if (post != null) {
                        if (currentPage == 1) {
                            partAdapter.setPost(post);  // Set the post initially
                        }

                        // Check for and handle new parts
                        List<Post.Part> newParts = post.getParts();
                        if (newParts != null && !newParts.isEmpty()) {
                            partAdapter.addParts(newParts);
                        }

                        // Update pagination info
                        if (post.getPagination() != null) {
                            currentPage++;
                            totalPage = post.getPagination().getLastPage();
                        } else {
                            Log.e("PaginationError", "Pagination object is null");
                        }

                        // Debug logs
                        Log.d("Pagination", "Current Page: " + currentPage);
                        Log.d("Pagination", "Total Pages: " + totalPage);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PartsActivity.this, "Failed to fetch post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PartsActivity.this, "Failed to fetch post", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                isLoading = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(PartsActivity.this, "Network error: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isLoading = false;
            }
        });
    }

